# gitlab not expanding variable used in parallel/matrix

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I am trying to pass the variable to parallel/matrix and do not see that getting expanded and the job failing. This is being set in the job from the environment variable. I am trying to echo the variable in script and see it shows the right value, but does not get substituted in parallel/matrix. Am I missing anything?

```
.common_deploy:
  script:
    - |
      echo "showing the regions from environment"
      echo $qa_regions
      echo "showing the regions from job variable"
      echo $REGIONS
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - REGION: "${REGIONS}"
      
DeployToQA:
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: qa
    REGIONS: $qa_regions
  extends:
    - .common_deploy
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      allow_failure: true
```

Here the variable `$qa_regions` has the value of "us-west-2,us-east-1", I was expecting to see the 2 jobs for those regions , but i am seeing the job as `DeployToQA: [${REGIONS}]`

Answer (score 9):

Variable expansion for the `parallel` keyword is currently not supported. There is an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/11549) for this request.

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) where variables can be used.

Comment: Thanks for responding, can i achieve this in any other different way apart from writing one more job to generate the job config

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any other way besides writing one more job

Comment: @danielnelz how it can be done using a different job, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @SrinivasBoga did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

To address the need for passing variables to the parallel:matrix effectively, I configured a workaround solution. My approach involved utilizing envsubst, a template file, and a trigger with the use of artifacts.

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - trigger

variables:
  PROJECTS: '["project1", "project2", "project3"]'

process:template:
  stage: trigger
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install gettext-base
  script:
    - envsubst '${PROJECTS}' < template.yml > template.gitlab-ci.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - template.gitlab-ci.yml

trigger:template:
  stage: trigger
  trigger:
    include: 
      - artifact: template.gitlab-ci.yml
        job: process:template
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
  needs:
    - job: process:template
```

Should have the `template.yml` file present within your repository:

```yaml
# template.yml
stages:
  - matrix

deploy:
  stage: matrix
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROJECT: ${PROJECTS}
  script:
    - echo "Deploying project = ${PROJECT}"
```

The final pipeline looks like this:
[image]

And in the output of each job from matrix we can see message from the echo:

- `deploy: [project1]` "Deploying project = project1"
- `deploy: [project2]` "Deploying project = project2"
- `deploy: [project3]` "Deploying project = project3"

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: I keep getting `The rules configuration prevented any jobs from being added to the pipeline` for some reason, any ideas why? on the `trigger::template`

Answer (score 1):

As already answerded by @danielnelz, variable expansion is currently not supported.

However, for a large amount of parallel jobs you could generate your pipeline dynamically by using [parent-child pipelines](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/04/24/parent-child-pipelines/#dynamically-generating-pipelines) instead.