# Parallel Matrix Blocking Gitlab Pipeline Execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My company uses self-managed AWS auto-scaling Docker runners, via Docker Machine. This configuration is [documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws/)

We have a single runner/runner-manager EC2 instance whose config.toml contains several different runner configs, all with different tags so that different groups in our Gitlab org get a dedicated runner, by use of runner tags, all from a single runner which spins up the appropriate executor for the corresponding tag in the job definition.

The runner for my group has been working flawlessly for months. Today I created a job using the parallel:matrix: keyword

```
Build Images:
  image: myimage
  stage: build
  script: 
    - docker build -f $DOCKERFILE -t $IMAGE_TAG
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOCKERFILE: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
        IMAGE_TAG: myrepo/myimage:standard
      - DOCKERFILE: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/super.Dockerfile
        IMAGE_TAG: myrepo/myimage:super
  rules:
    - when: always
```

When I push a commit neither this job or any others which should run are getting triggered. No error message or anything. The CI/CD->Jobs page does not show any jobs either.

This is the config.toml used on the runner manager. The runner I am attempting to run this job with is the first runner "my-runner"

```
concurrent = 100
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "my-runner"
  limit = 6
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "XYZABC"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "cache"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      BucketName = "mybucket"
      BucketLocation = "us-east-1"
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 600
    MaxBuilds = 10
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-docker-machine-%s"
    MachineOptions = ["amazonec2-instance-type=t3.medium", "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-xxxxxxxx", "amazonec2-security-group=my-security-group", "amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=xxxxxx", "amazonec2-root-size=32", "amazonec2-ami=ami-218k65t87w8b6posq", "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-xxxxxxxxx", "amazonec2-zone=a"]

    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = ["* * 13-23 * * mon-fri *"]
      Timezone = "UTC"
      IdleCount = 1
      IdleTime = 600

    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = ["* * 2-11 * * * *"]
      Timezone = "UTC"
      IdleCount = 0
      IdleTime = 300

[[runners]]
  name = "other-runner"
  limit = 6
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "LMNOP"
  executor = "docker+machine"
...
...
...
```

There are several more runners defined in this config, but they are all very similar. Each is registered with different tags.

**My Question:** In the [Gitlab CI docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#parallelmatrix) it says

> Multiple runners must exist, or a single runner must be configured to run multiple jobs concurrently

and to me it seems like multiple runners *do exist*, since the runner I am using has a limit of 6. Do the executors need to actually be spun up and sitting idle for this to work? Is there any way that I can get these parallel jobs to run without increasing my runner idle count?

**Edit:** Some additional information
This is just one job of about a dozen in this file(load-tests.yml)
My gitlab-ci.yml file imports jobs from about 10 other files via

```
include:
    - local: .gitlab/load-test.yml
```

The pipeline never get created. If I comment out this job then the pipeline runs, including the other jobs in this file.

I can provide the entire file verbatim, but everything works fine if this job is not included. I'm fairly experienced with Gitlab-CI so I'm sure that the issue lies with this job and/or the runner config when using these keywords.

Tag and other keys are set in defaults in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. None of them are of significance, things like default `variables`, default `before_script`, `cache`, etc.

**Edit:** We are using Gitlab SAAS(premium I believe, but not sure) with the runner manager using Gitlab-Runner v14.1.0

Comment: Is the pipeline created when you push? If not, double check the other parts of your CI configuration like `rules` for your jobs and `workflow:rules:` If you _only_ remove the `parallel:matrix:` key from this job, does the job get created? I also do not see your `tags:` key in the YAML. If you can provide your whole CI configuration file verbatim, that may be helpful. I think there may be some error there. I don't think the runner availability/idle count is the issue here.

Comment: The pipeline never get created. If I comment out this job then the pipeline runs, including jobs in this file, just without this job. I can provide the entire file verbatim, but this is just one job of about a dozen in this file(load-tests.yml), which is only a single file of about 10 which get imported into the .gitlab-ci.yml file with `include: [local: .gitlab/load-tests.yml]`. Tag and other keys are set in defaults in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. I am fairly experienced with gitlab-ci, just not this particular keyword, so I'm confident that the issue lies within the info that I have provided.

Comment: Hmmm. Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the problem in the latest version of GitLab. If I copy/paste your job definition into a project on its own, it works as expected. Even if you have only 1 runner with concurrency of `1`, the parallel jobs still get queued, they just don't run in parallel -- or even with 0 runners available, the pipeline should still be created but all the jobs will be stuck in "pending" state.

Comment: @sytech That comment is a huge help. It makes me think, this could be due to the Gitlab version we are using. We are using Gitlab SASS(premium I believe), with Gitlab-Runner v14.1.0 on the runner manager. The behavior you are describing is exactly what I was hoping to achieve as it would help DRY some of my jobs out. I will update the Gitlab-Runner version in the coming days and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate the issue, and it appears that the CI jobs are being generated as expected in the latest version of GitLab.

One potential concern I've identified is that variable expansion within the "parallel" keyword is currently unsupported. There's an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/11549) regarding this feature request. While it's unclear if this directly causes the problem of CI jobs not being created, it might be worth investigating.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) to see where variables can be utilized.

To work around the limitation of variable expansion in the "parallel" keyword, you can employ a method that involves "envsubst," a template file, and a trigger using artifacts. You can find a detailed example here [gitlab not expanding variable used in parallel/matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262596/gitlab-not-expanding-variable-used-in-parallel-matrix/76999674#76999674).